# 2018 Mac Mini no longer sending video or audio to TV via HDMI

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, television

I have a 2018 Mac Mini connected to a TCL Roku TV (43S403). There used to be no issue using the TV as a monitor, but recently, whenever I go to the input for my Mac it says "No signal (is it on?)". I'm running the latest versions of software on both devices, and I've tried several HDMI cables that work for other devices (e.g. the cable that connects my PS3 to another TV).

Restarting the TV, the Mac, and unplugging-replugging the HDMI cable at either end does nothing. Neither does hitting Detect Displays in the display preferences (which I'm only able to try because sharing the Mac Mini screen with my laptop works).